# How to fix "OSError: could not get source code" error when installing playsound?

Tags: python, python-playsound

```
    Collecting playsound
      Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [29 lines of output]
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
              main()
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return hook(config_settings)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ac5eef9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ac5eef9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires 
              self.run_setup()
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ac5eef9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
              self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9ac5eef9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
              exec(code, locals())
            File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1270, in getsource
              lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1252, in getsourcelines
              lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource
              raise OSError('could not get source code')
          OSError: could not get source code
          [end of output]
    
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a     problem with pip.

    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried to update Python version and pip version.

Answer (score 16):

This works to solve the issue:

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

Answer (score 5):

Try running

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
pip install playsound
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked in my case. When only upgrading the wheel the issue still persist. I am using Python version 3.12.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running **python 3.11** while [playsound 1.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) currently supports up to **python 3.9**. Try downgrading or using a venv like [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/virtualenv) to have multiple python versions available.

Answer (score 0):

playsound 1.3.0 does not currently have a whl, and the sdist version (.tar.gz) [has a bug](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/pull/146) when installed with pip.

If you don't want to wait for the fix and you have git installed, you can install the fixed version from my github.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/killjoy1221/playsound.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and I fixed it using:

```
python -m pip install playsound
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use following

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue related to building the wheel for the playsound module:It worked for me this way.

Step 1:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Step 2:  After upgrading setuptools, try installing the playsound module again

```
pip install playsound
```

Step 3:  Make sure you are using Python 3.x

```
pip install playsound --no-cache-dir
```

Step 4:

```
pip install playsound --only-binary playsound
```